# Debugging In Netbeans With xDebug

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

Am learning debugging using Netbeans (PHP) with xDebug. I have set Breakpoint(s) in a php file am using but it seems anytime i start the debugging (clicking the start debug button) the system switches to the "index.php" file in the parent folder. The file am using is in a child folder of the folder containing the "index.php" file.  How come the debugging goes to the "index.php" file?

What am i doing wrong?  Am very new in using IDE debugging so help me out. I always use print statements to debug my code but i have decided to use professional debugging. Am just new in this area so help me know what is going on.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to look at:

1. Tools->Options, PHP Section->Debugging Tab - Uncheck 'Stop at First
   Line'
2. File->Project Properties - Run Configuration - Advanced  - You can
   set the entry URL for the debugger.  The default is to begin with
   the index page, but you can set it to ask for a url when the
   debugger is invoked.